# Array with words separated by comma with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

My array looks like this:

```
["colors,cars,boks"]
```

What I need is this:

```
["colors","cars","books]
```

This is what i've tried:

```
$.makeArray(my_arr)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```js
var str = ["colors,cars,boks"];
    var res = str[0].split(",");
    console.log(res);
```